# Speed up my sort

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a problem. My task is to fetch users from CoreData and sort them based on sum of theirs scores.

As a result, I came up with:
 1. I fetch users from CoreData.
 2. I sort them using:

```
users = users?.map({ (user) -> (User, Int) in
     return (user, (user.tasks as! Set<Task>).reduce(0, { $0 + ($1.score!.intValue)})
}).sorted(by: { (e1, e2) -> Bool in
     return e1.1 > e2.1
}).map({ (user, sum) -> User in
     return user
})
```

This works, but the whole process is very slow. Is there a better way achieve my goal?

Edited:

Ok, I added related moels:

[image: User]
[image]

I also tried `NSSortDescriptor`, but I didn't find any way to sort my data during fetch request.

Comment: *"very slow"* does mean what exactly? You probably should not sort the users by hand but sort them in the core data fetch request or whatever you do to retrieve them.

Comment: the sort takes about 1 s

Comment: How many user objects are we talking about?

Comment: around 100 users and 100000 tasks

Comment: Can you add the details of your Core Data model, at least the details that apply to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Denormalize the data.  That is store their score sums in the user object.  You have to be careful every time you insert, delete or update a score, to also update the user object so it is best to make methods that do that is the ONLY place that you update the score.

Comment: best add this method directly to `User` class or to an `UserController`